# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '###' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I wrote this function to catch event when UI click at button (type of Radio Type)

```
 const onChangeType = (value: any, id: any) => {
    
    let tempArrOption: any = [];

    arrayOption.map((opt: any, index: any) => {
      tempArrOption[index] = { ...opt };
    });

    tempArrOption.forEach((opt: any) => {
      if (opt.id === id) {
        opt.type.forEach((type: any) => {          
          if (type.name !== value.name) {
            type.isSelect = false;
            return { ...type, isSelect: !type.isSelect };
          }
          type.isSelect = true;
          type.isSelect = value.isSelect;
          return type;
        });
      }
    });
    setArrayOption(tempArrOption);
}
```

Everything just fine in the first time I pick one of those "type", but when I come back and click another type, the error happen and I'm so confused to solve it. How can I change the value in this issue. Please tell me where I'm so wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error looks pretty clear to me: the property "isSelect" is read-only. What are the objects that the code is handling? DOM elements?

Comment: `isSelect` is the value of object "type", and "type" I retrieved from DB not DOM elements

Comment: Object properties can be made read-only in JavaScript, so some software somewhere is doing that.